# Windows Server stuck on Checking for Updates

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012

[Windows Server 2012 Standard]

I have been tasked with updating some servers here at the office, and one of them is giving me problems. Windows Update has now been in the "Checking for updates..." phase for 5 days, with no signs of completing. (It has not had updates applied for over a year, so it definitely has needed patches.) Troubleshooting tasks done so far:

- Restarted the server
- Stopped the WU service, deleted the contents of the `Software Distribution` folder, and restarted service
- Looked through Windows Logs; don't see anything obvious

The server is also running (a currently unused install of) SharePoint 2013 - not sure if that is a factor in this stuck state or not. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Welp I informed my mgr of the situation - since we're not using this server any more, we'll be decommissioning it, so the problem in moot at this point. Thanks in any case for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Window Server 2012 is based on [Windows 8 code and here the Microsoft doesn't fix the long update scan](https://superuser.com/a/983117/174557) like [in Windows 8.1/2012 R2](https://superuser.com/a/1189745/174557).

So upgrade to 2012 R2 + apply the fix or accept the slow update scanning.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous I have no idea. Phone Microsoft for license question.

Comment: Just sounds crazy that MS suggestion to the fix of a problem of non R2 would be to upgrade to a version you have to pay for rather than fixing what people have already paid for instead that's still under support.... if that's the case... not sure though -- I'll assume it is without the call based on vague memory recollection.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous I asked that MS for Win8 when I read the first question some time ago and here I got the answer from my contacts that they threat 8.1 as free service pack for win8, so here they suggest to upgrade to 8.1 to fix it. And because 2012 is based on 8 and 2012R2 on 8.1, his fix is to also upgrade to the newer server.

Comment: R2 DataCenter has this exact same issue.

Comment: @tbone [apply linked fix](https://superuser.com/a/1189745/174557)

Answer (score 1):

Perform the below Steps to resolve the Windows Update Issue,
 - Make sure that System Date/Time is Updated with time Server. Change the settings by right-clicking the clock in the **taskbar >>  Adjust date/time >> Internet Time.**
 - Turn Off firewall for all the networks.
 - Restart and Check for updates.

Above steps seems to be a basic but it should solve your problem.

Comment: I don't see " taskbar >> Adjust date/time >> Internet Time"